# How to access the data of this json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given this json response:

```
[
    {
        "diccioDatosForm": {
            "errorMessage": "Verifique los datos invalidos ingresados...",
            "encargadoLocalidad": "Ingrese un valor",
            "responseStatus": "ERR",
            "segundoNombre": "OK",
            "encargadoProvincia": "Ingrese un valor"
        }
    },
    {
        "listaEncargados": []
    }
]
```

I need to access the elements of the key 'diccioDatosForm'.
When I print the json with an alert (`alert(responseData)`), I get:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

and I don't get anything when trying to do this:

```
alert(responseData.diccioDatosForm.errorMessage)
```

Comment: what's the method you used to get this response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
responseData[0].diccioDatosForm.errorMessage
```

`responseData` itself is an array contains of 2 elements

Answer (score 2):

Your `responseData` object is an array with objects within.  As a result you must use an index when referencing the internal objects.

```
responseData[0].diccioDatosForm.errorMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are alerting the array that is being returned.
To access the field you want, you should do:

```
responseData[0].diccioDatosForm.diccioDatosForm
```

I know that what I will say is not part of your question, but I suggest that you review your JSON structure, because its strange to have an array of two different things.

I would use something like this:

```
{
    "configs": {
        "segundoNombre": "OK",
        "encargadoProvincia": "Ingrese un valor",
        "encargadoLocalidad": "Ingrese un valor"
    },
    "error": {
        "message": "Verifique los datos invalidos ingresados..."
    },
    "itens": []   // "encargados" list here
}
```

Doing this you will have standard to use through yout application. To acess the message error you could do:

```
responseData.error.message
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to find the value of a parameter that's in an object that's the first element of an array in your JSON. In plain Javascript, that means:

```
var data = [{"diccioDatosForm": {"errorMessage": /* ... */]

// grab diccioDatosForm from first array element:
var diccioDatosForm = data[0].diccioDatosForm;
```